# How do I find a function that is proportional to the definite integral of itself and a trigonometric function in a limited space?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

$$
f(x) = x - \int_0^{\pi/2} f(x)\sin(x)dx
$$
How do you solve this equation for the function $f(x)$?
The question had a hint to use integration by parts.

Comment: The equation you wrote says $f(x) = x - C$ for some constant $C$.  The integral is just some constant.  (using x's in the integral is confusing too.. are any of those x's the same as the x on the left side?)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**.

$\int_0^{π/2} f(x)\sin(x) \ dx=a$  is a constant that depends on $f$. So $f$ has the form $f(x)=x-a$. Hence
$$f(x)= x - \int_0^{π/2} (x-a)\sin(x)dx$$ By integration by parts you can find $f$ depending on $a$.

Then find the possible values of $a$ using the initial equation $\int_0^{π/2} f(x)\sin(x)=a \ dx$.You will be done...